# Question about foundations of the uniform shrinkage prior

Tags: bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, minimax

I am collecting papers about the uniform shrinkage prior for hierarchical Bayesian model.
In ["A prior for the variance in hierarchical models"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.1224&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of Michael J. Daniels it is stated at the end of page two that:

> An alternative proper prior, shown to give a minimax estimator for the k means for the above model by Strawderman (1971) under certain conditions, would be to place a uniform prior on the shrinkage parameter.

The mentioned paper by Strawderman (1971) is ["Proper Bayes Minimax Estimators of the Multivariate Normal Mean"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2958496).

I do not understand in what sense this article explicates the quote of Daniels (maybe the paper is too technical for me and I missed the point). 
If somebody has some hints regarding the article or more generally can explain the quoted sentence, I will appreciate it.